# Vue3: API-Calls to a Laravel API on Apache server with Active Directory authentication

Tags: laravel, vuejs3

I have to write a Vue3 component for a website which requires authentication via Active Directory. The server is Apache, the authentication is done with GSSAPI. The endpoint is a Laravel 10 API which works perfectly on my local machine (without the authentication).

In Vue I try to send data to the API using fetch(). This fails because of the missing authentication. I always get a 401.

Here's the code snippet for fetch:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json"},
    body: JSON.stringify({
      pageid: pageid,
      template: sectionTemplate.value,
      order: order,
      user: user,
    })
})
```

I used Insomnia to test it with and without authentication. When I do it with the Vue component the entries in the log file look the same, they only also contain the referrer page and the browser's user agent. Here's an example of what the access.log looks like.

```
12.34.56.78 - - [26/Mar/2024:13:52:35 +0100] "POST /api/section HTTP/1.1" 401 671 "-" "-"
```

With authentication in Insomnia enabled I get:

```
12.34.56.78 - AD-Username [26/Mar/2024:13:53:31 +0100] "POST /api/section HTTP/1.1" 200 320 "-" "-"
```

How can I solve the problem? What do I need to send with my request in Vue to tell the webserver that I'm already authenticated?